# .htaccess added Cors-headers are missing from time to time

Tags: .htaccess, header, apache2

Because the frontend runs on another port I have .htaccess file for development (no CORS in production, don't worry):

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers *
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods *
```

My app does the same backend-call several times. Sometimes after three or four of those (which went fine) suddenly the CORS-headers are missing from the call (and naturally CORS kicks in and the frontend doesn't get any response.).

Apparently the .htaccess file is ignored sometimes.

Apache-error log does not say anything.

Any idea what could cause this or how to debug?

- FF 102.10.0esr
- Chrome 113.0
- Apache 2.4.56

Comment: "Apache-error log does not say anything." is the request recorded in the "access log"? The `.htaccess` file would only be "ignored" if the request did not actually reach your server (ie. cached client-side / proxy?).

Comment: @MrWhite. Interestingly they are listed with a 403 return. So there must be some error with my authentication there. But still - how does CORS kicks in on those 403ers and not the 200ers?

Comment: "how does CORS kicks in on those 403ers and not the 200ers?" - I would expect it to be the other way round - if the only directives are those as posted in your question? The directive `Header add ...` would only set the header on "200 OK" responses. To also set on non-200 responses (ie. 403s) then you would need the `always` _condition_. eg. `Header always add ...`. Should you not be using `set` here - are you setting multiple headers?

Comment: If your server does not send the CORS headers on HTTP errors, then web browsers report a CORS error instead of showing you the HTTP error. The comment from @MrWhite is your solution.

Comment: @MrWhite This was the solution indeed. Thank you very much, I didn't know about `always` and assumed this as default behavior. Now this reveals a very critical bug in my application since there should not be random 403s but this is non of you or this thread's business. Formulate it as an answer, I'll accept and you get point though.

Comment: @Paflow I've added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
> Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers *
> Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods *
> ```

These headers will only be set on "successful" (ie. 2xx HTTP status) responses, since the default "condition" (or *group* of headers) is `onsuccess`. In other words, the above is the same as:

```
Header onsuccess add Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Header onsuccess add Access-Control-Allow-Headers *
Header onsuccess add Access-Control-Allow-Methods *
```

(`onsuccess` is *optional*, since that is the default.)

However, it would seem you are (erroneously) serving a 403 Forbidden response, so these headers are not being set (and you see a CORS error). In order to set the headers on both 2xx and non-2xx responses you need to use the `always` condition instead. For example:

```
Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Headers *
Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Methods *
```

This can get a little confusing/messy. `onsuccess` and `always` (known as "conditions") are effectively two separate groups of headers. You can add a header to both groups and if you want to `edit` (or `merge` or `unset`) an existing header then you need to know in which group the header was initially set/added.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#header